# Spring kafka: failed to send Message to channel payload must not be null

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have two project microservices with spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE, the first microservice sends a user to a topic and the second microservice consumes this message, when i send the user it shows the error below in the second microservice

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'verification-token-in'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: payload must not be null
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:451) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:360) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:271) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:70) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:64) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:188) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$000(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:54) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:288) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:279) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter$1.doWithRetry(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:79) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter$1.doWithRetry(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:73) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180) ~[spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:73) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:39) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:792) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:736) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2100(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:246) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1025) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: payload must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessage.<init>(MutableMessage.java:57) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessage.<init>(MutableMessage.java:53) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessageBuilder.withPayload(MutableMessageBuilder.java:86) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessageBuilderFactory.withPayload(MutableMessageBuilderFactory.java:35) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessageBuilderFactory.withPayload(MutableMessageBuilderFactory.java:26) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$ContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:265) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:540) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:417) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

kafka dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Output (First Microservice):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        verification-token-out:
          destination: verification.token
          contentType: application/json
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
          zkNodes: localhost
          defaultZkPort: 2181

public interface UserStreams {

    String OUTPUT_VERIFICATION_TOKEN = "verification-token-out";

    @Output(UserStreams.OUTPUT_VERIFICATION_TOKEN)
    public MessageChannel outputVerificationToken();

}

@EnableBinding(UserStreams.class)
public class UserServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private UserStreams source;

    @Override
    public void createVerificationTokenForUser(UserDto userSender) {
     source.outputVerificationToken().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(userSender).build());
    }

}
```

Input (Second Microservice):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        verification-token-in:
          destination: verification.token
          contentType: application/octet-stream
          originalContentType: application/json
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
          zkNodes: localhost
          defaultZkPort: 2181

public interface MailStreams {

    String INPUT_VERIFICATION_TOKEN = "verification-token-in";

    @Input(MailStreams.INPUT_VERIFICATION_TOKEN)
    SubscribableChannel inputVerificationToekn();

}

@EnableBinding(MailStreams.class)
public class Receiver {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

    @StreamListener(MailStreams.INPUT_VERIFICATION_TOKEN)
    public void verificationToken(final UserDto payload) {
        LOGGER.info("Received payload='{}'", payload);
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind to show more stack trace? And what is the Spring Cloud Stream version do you use? And what Spring Kafka and Apache Kafka per se? More over it would really be much better if you can share a simple project with us on GitHub to let us to reproduce it on our side. Sounds like a bug, although I believer this was fixed before in some version...

Comment: `[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]` it is [fixed in 1.3.x ](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/993).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]`

The problem was due to an improper content type; this is fixed in [1.3.x.](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/993) (Ditmars).

Comment: what is the version of spring boot that is compatible with spring-cloud-stream-1.3.x ?

Comment: 1.5.x. Currently 1.5.14.

Comment: Try removing the `originalContentType` and `contentType` configs from the consumer.